# Error in use a code from github in string stream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I used a code from [here](https://github.com/UnaNancyOwen/Kinect2Sample) (Color folder) in Visual Studio 2013 to capture color data from Kinect v2. But when I want to run the code, these lines of code in `util.h` file causes a compile error:

```
#define ERROR_CHECK( ret )                                         \
if (FAILED(ret)){
                                                                   \
    std::stringstream ss;                                          \
    std::ss << "failed " #ret " " << std::hex << ret << std::endl; \
    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str().c_str());                    \
}
```

And my Visual Studio below draws `ss` a red line and is written: `namespace "std" has no member "ss" below <<: expected a ";" and below throw: expected a declaration`.
What is this part of code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong, changing `std::ss` to `ss` should help:

```
#define ERROR_CHECK( ret )                                    \
if (FAILED(ret)) {                                            \
                                                              \
    std::stringstream ss;                                     \
    ss << "failed " #ret " " << std::hex << ret << std::endl; \
    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str().c_str());               \
}
```

Another error in the code snippet you show that there was a line continuation missing after the `if(statement)`.
Also ensure that `<sstream>` is included when using this.

The macro seems to be already fixed in the [original code](https://github.com/UnaNancyOwen/Kinect2Sample/blob/master/sample/Color/util.h), but can be that other buggy versions of `util.h` are existing in the other sample folders.

Comment: the error is changed: this declaration has no storage class or type specifire;

Comment: how can run this code without error in visual studio?

Comment: @masoomi As mentioned you probably can't. GitHub contains a lot of crap. Ask the author at GitHub maybe.

Comment: @masoomi Asking that again and again won't get you better answered. My best advice is, you shouldn't download random code from the internet when you don't understand the language yet.

Comment: @masoomi You may have noticed that I also fixed a missing line continuation \ after the `if()` statement.

Answer (score -1):

It may not be what you wanted, but does your program work if you just comment every line? It is "just" a stringstream that only purpose (as far as I can see) is to print out when an error occurs. Replace it with some kind of printf() if you really want to see the output.

```
#define ERROR_CHECK( ret )                                        
if (FAILED(ret)){

   // std::stringstream ss;                                     
   // std::ss << "failed " #ret " " << std::hex << ret << std::endl; 
   // throw std::runtime_error(ss.str().c_str()); 
printf("Error : FAILED(ret)");

}
```

This way your code compiles but you do not have the original throw of an error IFF an error occurs

Comment: can you test this code? need to opencv and kinectsdk2 libraries

Comment: _"replace it with printf()"_ Huh?? Do you even understand what that code does?

Comment: @masoomi _"need to opencv and kinectsdk2 libraries"_ Not for this piece of code, no.

Comment: I edited the post for more understanding. If it does not match "Do you even understand what that code does?" then please tell me what that code does

Comment: @John.A.Myer What you show won't compile either. It's a macro definition. And why whould be `printf()` better than throwing an exception?

Comment: My approach is to comment the functionality of the macro and hoping it will compile that way. I know the functionality is lost then, but it may still help to run the code

Comment: @John.A.Myer To start with: You're missing the line continuations. Also `ret` is stringified in the original code. Your `printf()` statement would just print `Error : FAILED(ret)`, not very useful without seeing what `ret` originally was. So please stop people advising about things you obviously don't understand.

Comment: I tried to help as far as I could. Sorry about that. Won't happen again